# in code not working properly of image view and button?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, null, uiimageview, uibutton

*i have work with imageview and button .if imageview is null or
    unselected then button is set disabled and message print like this 
    @"select image".. but in my code not working ..
    image view dont allow null value . what error in this code . 
    give me suggetion thanks ...*

```
     -(void)viewDidLoad 

 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
      if(self.imageview == null) // imageview_outlet
      Btn.enabled=yes;//button_outlate
         NSLog(@"select image in imageview");
      }
         else
      Btn.enables=no;//button outlet
     }
          }
```

Comment: if(self.imageview.image == null) and try

Comment: Hey your issue exist or over

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
if(imageview.image == nil)
{// imageview_outlet
    Btn.enabled=YES;//button_outlate
    NSLog(@"select image in imageview");
}
else
{
    Btn.enabled=NO;//button outlet
}
```

I think best solution is to use tag.

```
//somewhere when you select or add the image you change the imageview tag 2
imageview.tag =2;


imageview.tag =1; //bydefault set tag 1



if(imageview.tag == 1)
{// imageview_outlet
    Btn.enabled=YES;//button_outlate
    NSLog(@"select image in imageview");
}
else
{
    Btn.enabled=NO;//button outlet
}
```

Comment: imageview he mentioned as // imageview_outlet and as your idea he need to set tag =1 , the imageview object is present in the view always so that's not correct i think so

Comment: I think we also set the tag to image view in the storyboard.

Comment: obviously but we didn't have much difference between question and answer at the your point of the moment